# How do you blacklist an email sender in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, blacklist, email-bounces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure Gmail so that filtered user gets an NDR (non-deliverable receipt) or "bounce" message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/how-to-configure-gmail-so-that-filtered-user-gets-an-ndr-non-deliverable-receipt)

Because of the way Gmail handles email addresses, I've been getting emails from a group, for a similar email to mine.  While I've marked them as spam, I want to do better at stopping those emails, and have seen in the past where sending emails to the group doesn't work too well since most people won't remember to fix their reply-to-all list.

What I'd like to do is bounce those specific senders, so that I never get those messages at all, and they get a bounceback message, so eventually they'll figure it out and quit sending the messages.

How do you setup a sender to be bounced, so I don't get the message, and they see the bounce?